# Error: stack/package nxt_python not found

Tags: ros, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10, and installed ROS. Then I tried to setup ros_nxt http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/electric

To verify the setup, I run nxt_python, but got the following error.

```
$ rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py 
[rospack] Error: stack/package nxt_python not found
```

I tried roscd and got the same error, but rosls works

```
$ rosls nxt_python
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
$ roscd nxt_python
roscd: No such package/stack 'nxt_python'
```

any suggestion to debugging this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44270/error:-stack/package-nxt_python-not-found/) by [nxlong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3240/nxlong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you don't have your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable set up correctly.

Take a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment and http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0